# code is working properly in Core PHP but writing coding in WordPress

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, code, csv

```php
function generate_pdf($array)
{
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
foreach ( $array as $line ) {
    $val = explode(",", $line);
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
fclose($fp);
}

$array = array(
    'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
    '123,456,789',
    '"aaa","bbb"'
);

generate_pdf($array);
```

Here's my code generating correct csv file, But When I'm implementing this in my Custom Plugin It's generating Coding in .csv file

Comment: Can you rephrase your last sentence? It says your code X but when in your custom plugin it also does X which doesn't make sense, what do you mean by generate coding in CSV file? How are you using the code in your plugin? it isn't clear what the WP version of this looks like or how it misbehaves

Comment: I think I’ve seen this before... instead of outputting just the CSV or PDF you’re also getting HTML in the output, correct?  If so then you’ll need ob_start() at the beginning.  Let me see if I can find my solution.

Answer (score 0):

When I attempted something similar I experienced the same issue where the HTML code of the page I was generating the CSV from would be included within the CSV mixed with the data I actually wanted.

The two things I figured out, after searching and reading and reading and searching was to use `ob_end_clean();` before I start outputting the content of the CSV.  `ob_end_clean()` is 'Output Buffers End/Clean` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php

I also added `die()` at the end of the CSV output code to, well, exit the process.  You can also use `exit()`.

```
function generate_pdf( $array ) {
    ob_end_clean(); //ADD THIS LINE
    header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');

    $fp = fopen( 'php://output', 'wb' );
    foreach( $array as $line ) {
        $val = explode( ',', $line );
        fputcsv( $fp, $val );
    }
    fclose( $fp );
    die(); //add this as well
}
```

Comment: Thanks man ! It worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  When it happened to me I sank like 8 hours into finding a solution.  Hope I spared you that agony.  Please remember to accept my answer so other users that have the same issue can quickly see that it’s a feasible solution.